# Сделайте ревью кода

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода

Сделал рефакторинг. Какая работа была проведена:

1. разделил на методы, вынес многие в BaseManager
2. упростил названия переменных
3. перенёс все try-catch в базовый класс BaseManager
4. сгруппировал методы по доступу (вверху private, далее publiс)
5. было:

   ```
   protected RestClient GetApiClient()
   {
       var client = new RestClient
       {
           BaseUrl = new Uri(_baseApiServer)
       };
       return client;
   }
   ```

   стало:

   ```
   protected RestClient ApiClient
   {
       get
       { 
           return new RestClient
           {
               BaseUrl = new Uri(_baseApiServer)
           };
       }
   }
   ```
6. Было

   ```
   private async Task<string> GetObjVal(string groupId)
   ```

   стало:

   ```
   private async Task<JSON> GetObjValue(string groupId)
   ```

   теперь видно, что метод возвращает JSON. Для это пришлось ввести класс JSON,
   а в нём поле Value
7. Вынес константы:

   ```
   private const string getFormsAPI = "anketa.list";
   private const string getFormAPI = "anketa.get";
   private const string requestName = "request";
   private const string idKey = "id";

   private static class API
   {
       public static string GetForms { get { return "anketa.list"; } } // ! const бессмысленно? Раз отсутствует set
       public static string GetForm = "anketa.get"; 
   }
   ```

   мотив - чтобы избавится от префикса API в константах.
8. Как лучше?

   ```
   Parameter request = ....
   ```

   или лучше

   ```
   Parameter requestParam
   ```

   или

   ```
   requestP
   ```

   чтобы было понятно, что это параметр. Или по типу можно понять, наведя мышкой?
9. В UserName.cs я бросаю исключение, как мне посоветовали. Но везде по коду
   ошибки пишутся в лог. Согласно стилю предыдущего кода мне тоже надо в лог писать?
10. JSON.cs, RootObject.cs, UserName.cs поместил в папку Model
11. Избавился от dynamic

Если какие-то пункты некорректны, исправьте, пожалуйста. + напишите что ещё исправить

```
public class BaseManager
{
    private static readonly string _baseApiServer = "https://api.sendsay.ru/clu206"; // ! подчёркивания
    protected const string getGroupsAPI = "group.list";
    protected readonly IApiConfig ApiConfig;
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;
    protected CancellationToken Token { get { return new CancellationTokenSource().Token; } }

    public BaseManager(IApiConfig config)
    {
        ApiConfig = config;
        Logger = config.Logger;
    }

    protected IRestRequest GetBaseRequest(string action)
    {
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(_baseApiServer, Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("apiversion", "100");
        request.AddParameter("json", "1");
        UserName username = new UserName(ApiConfig.UserName);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                      new
                      {
                          one_time_auth = new
                          {
                              login = username.Login,
                              sublogin = username.Sublogin,
                              passwd = ApiConfig.Password
                          },
                          action = action
                      });
        request.AddParameter("request", json);
        return request;
    }

    protected RestClient ApiClient
    {
        get
        { 
            return new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = new Uri(_baseApiServer)
            };
        }
    }

    protected string AddObjectToParam(Parameter param, string key, string value)
    {
        value = key == "obj" ? value : '"'+value+'"';
        string paramVal = param.Value.ToString();
        return paramVal.Insert(paramVal.Length - 1, ",\"" + key + "\":" + value + "");
    }

    protected async Task<IRestResponse> GetResponseAsync(IRestRequest request)
    {
        IRestResponse response = null; // !
        try
        {
            response = await ApiClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, Token);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger?.Error($"Response getting error: {e.Message}");
        }
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Logger?.Error($"Server return error: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected T GetDeserialized<T>(string content)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger?.Error($"Deserialization error: {e.Message}. Probably API structure has changed");
        }
        return (T)(object)null; // !
    }
}




    public class SubscriberManager : BaseManager, ISubscriberManager
    {
        private FieldManager fieldMng;
        private const string getMembersAPI = "member.set";
        private const string emailKey = "email";
        private const string newbieConfirmKey = "newbie.confirm";
        private const string newbieLetterConfirmKey = 
             "newbie.letter.confirm";
        private const string objKey = "obj";

        public SubscriberManager(IApiConfig config) : base(config)
        {
            fieldMng = new FieldManager(ApiConfig);
        }

        private async Task<JSON> GetObjValue(string groupId)
        {
            StringBuilder objVal = new StringBuilder("{");
            IEnumerable<FormWithQuests> formsWithQuests = await 
             fieldMng.GetFormsWithQuestsAsync();
            foreach (FormWithQuests formWithQuests in formsWithQuests)
            {
                IEnumerable<Quest> quests = formWithQuests.Quests;
                if (!quests.Any()) continue;



objVal.Append('"').Append(formWithQuests.Id).Append('"').Append(":{");
                for (int i = 0; i < quests.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Quest quest = quests.ElementAt(i);
                    objVal.Append('"').Append(quest.Id).Append('"')
                          .Append(':')
                          .Append('"').Append(quest.Name).Append('"');
                    if (i < quests.Count() - 1)
                    {
                        objVal.Append(',');
                    }
                }
                objVal.Append("},");
            }
            objVal.Append("\"-group\": {\"" + groupId + "\":\"1\"}}");
            return new JSON(objVal.ToString());
        }



        public async Task<int> ValidateRequestAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                IRestResponse resp = await GetResponseAsync(GetBaseRequest(getGroupsAPI)); // ! уже есть try-catch внутри
                return 200;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger?.Error(e);
                return (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
            }
        }



            public async Task<Person> AddAsync(Subscriber subscriber)
            {
                Parameter request = GetBaseRequest(getMembersAPI).Parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "request"); // ! requestP
                request.Value = AddObjectToParam(request, emailKey, subscriber.Email);
                request.Value = AddObjectToParam(request, newbieConfirmKey, subscriber.OptIn ? "1" : "0");
                if (subscriber.OptIn)
                    request.Value = AddObjectToParam(request, newbieLetterConfirmKey, subscriber.TemplateId.ToString());

                request.Value = AddObjectToParam(request, objKey, (await GetObjValue(subscriber.GroupId)).Value);

                IRestResponse response = await GetResponseAsync(GetBaseRequest(getMembersAPI));
                SubscriberResponse data = GetDeserialized<SubscriberResponse>(

response.Content);
            return data.Member;
        }
    }


public class SendSayManager : ISendSayManager
{
    public IApiConfig ApiConfig { get; set; }
    public IListManager Lists { get; set; }
    public ISubscriberManager Subscribers { get; set; }
    public IFieldManager Fields { get; set; }
    public IEmailTemplateManager EmailTemplates { get; set; }
    public SendSayManager(IApiConfig apiConfig)
    {
        ApiConfig = apiConfig;
        Lists = new ListManager(ApiConfig);
        Subscribers = new SubscriberManager(ApiConfig);
        Fields = new FieldManager(apiConfig);
        EmailTemplates = new EmailTemplateManager(apiConfig);
    }
}



public class ListManager : BaseManager, IListManager
{
    public ListManager(IApiConfig config) : base(config)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IList<Group>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        IRestResponse response = await GetResponseAsync(GetBaseRequest(getGroupsAPI));
        ListResult lists = GetDeserialized<ListResult>(response.Content);
        return lists.List;
    }
}


public class FieldManager : BaseManager, IFieldManager
{
    private static class API
    {
        public static string GetForms { get { return "anketa.list"; } } // ! const бессмысленно? Раз отсутствует set
        public static string GetForm = "anketa.get"; 
    }

    private const string getFormsAPI = "anketa.list";
    private const string getFormAPI = "anketa.get";
    private const string requestName = "request";
    private const string idKey = "id";

    public FieldManager(IApiConfig config) : base(config)
    {
    }

    private async Task<string[]> GetFormIdsAsync(string apiMethod)
    {
        IRestResponse formsResp = await GetResponseAsync(GetBaseRequest(apiMethod));
        string[] formIds = GetDeserialized<FormList>(formsResp.Content).List.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
        return formIds;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<QuestObj>> GetQuestsFromJSON(string formId)
    {
        IRestRequest readFormRequest = GetBaseRequest(getFormAPI);
        Parameter request = readFormRequest.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == requestName);
        request.Value = AddObjectToParam(request, idKey, formId);
        IRestResponse readFormResp = await GetResponseAsync(readFormRequest);
        IEnumerable<QuestObj> questsFromJSON = GetDeserialized<RootObject>(readFormResp.Content).Obj.Quests.Select(x => x.Value);
        return questsFromJSON;
    }

    public async Task<IList<Quest>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        IList<Quest> quests = new List<Quest>();
        foreach (string formId in await GetFormIdsAsync(API.GetForms))
        {
            foreach (QuestObj quest in await GetQuestsFromJSON(formId))
            {
                quests.Add(new Quest(quest.Id, quest.Name));
            }
        }
        return quests;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<FormWithQuests>> GetFormsWithQuestsAsync()
    {
        IList<FormWithQuests> formsWithQuests = new List<FormWithQuests>();
        foreach (string formId in await GetFormIdsAsync(API.GetForms))
        {
            IList<Quest> quests = new List<Quest>();
            foreach (QuestObj quest in await GetQuestsFromJSON(formId))
            {
                quests.Add(new Quest(quest.Id, quest.Name));
            }
            formsWithQuests.Add(new FormWithQuests(formId, quests));
        }
        return formsWithQuests;
    }
}



class JSON
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public JSON(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}


public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("obj")]
    public Obj Obj { get; set; }
}

public class Obj
{
    [JsonProperty("quests")]
    public Dictionary<string, QuestObj> Quests { get; set; }
}

public class QuestObj
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}




    class UserName
    {
        private const char delimeter = '|';
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Sublogin { get; set; }
        public UserName(string username)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Username is not filled", nameof(username));
            }
            string[] logins = username.Split(delimeter);
            if (logins.Length == 2)
            {
                Login = logins[0];
                Sublogin = logins[1];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The parameter {nameof(username)} has incorrect content.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *жалуются на качество* - то есть у них есть критерии качества, о необходимости соответствия кода которым вас уведомили перед тем, как вы начали это все писать; или как? Какие проблемы с качеством были выявлены в этом коде?

Comment: основная жалоба - на некорректную десериализацию,  там где делегат. что использовал dynamic, return (dynamic)

Comment: отрефакторить я не успел - а им надо чтобы мой комичченный код был совершенный и тут же готов к проду

Comment: Опишите реализуемую функциональность и назначение кода. Подробная инструкция есть в полном описании метки [инспекция-кода]

Comment: Доработка сервиса для сбора контактов (email, телефонов) - разработка интеграции с ESP системой SendSay (sendsay.ru)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Обязанности:
Встроить в текущую архитектуру сервиса функционал новой интеграции (back/front -end). Функционал реализует взаимодействие с SendSay, вызывая его API: получение групп, форм, доп. полей; добавление подписчиков

Стек технологий:
C# / ASP.Net MVC / MS SQL / EntityFramework / TFS / TypeScript
Инструменты:
MS Visual Studio, MS SQL Server, Postman

Comment: А вы unit тесты писали?

Comment: ох сколько там `var-type`... Читать сложно так же как и рефакторить.

Comment: что приходит в `readFormResp.Content`, зачем обрамлять его в `[]` и парсить как массив? а потом брать только первый элемент???

Answer (score 4):

Надо понимать, что в компании могут быть какие-то свои стандарты на код. Вам менеджер что-то по этому поводу давал почитать? Публичный кодревью на митингах проходил?

Сугубо мое личное.

1) Параметры в публичных методах нужно проверять перед их использованием. У вас ни в конструкторах классов, ни в публичных методах такой проверки не делается.

Было:

```
class UserName
{
    private const char delimeter = '|';
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Sublogin { get; set; }
    public UserName(string username)
    {
        Login = username.Split(delimeter)[0];
        Sublogin = username.Split(delimeter)[1];
    }
}
```

Стало:

```
class UserName
{
    private const char delimeter = '|';
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Sublogin { get; set; }
    public UserName(string username)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The parameter {nameof(username)} is empty.");
        }

        //прежде чем присваивать данные из параметра нужно убедиться
        //в том, что они имеют условно правильные значения
        var logins = username.Split(delimeter);
        if (logins.Length == 2)
        {
            Login = logins[0];
            Sublogin = logins[1];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The parameter {nameof(username)} has incorrect content.");
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, в студии уже есть готовый функционал

[image: вызов контекстного меню на параметре метода]
[image: вызов меню рефакторинга]

2) Еще это.

Было:

```
public async Task<IList<List>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = GetApiClient();
            var request = GetBaseRequest("group.list");
            var cancelTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var resp = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<ListResult>(request, cancelTokenSrc.Token);
            if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created && resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Logger?.Error($"Server return error: {resp.StatusCode}");
            }
            try
            {
                ListResult lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListResult>(resp.Content);
                return lists.List;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger?.Error(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger?.Error(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Стало:

```
//давать кастомные названия совпадающие с названиями классов .Net фреймворка
    //это как бы моветон, это я про ваш List
    public async Task<IList<List>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        //в try/catch должно быть только то, что потенциально может вызвать исключение
        var client = GetApiClient();
        //"group.list" - это значение должно быть конст.полем класса
        var request = GetBaseRequest("group.list");
        var cancelTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var resp = null; //укажите какой здесь должен быть тип
        try
        {
            resp = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<ListResult>(request, cancelTokenSrc.Token);
            if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created && resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Logger?.Error($"Server return error: {resp.StatusCode}");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //по-идее у вас должны быть свои кастомные классы исключений
            //получив здесь исключение, вы должны перебросить наверх уже
            //свое кастомное, кот. будет уже там наверху записано в лог
            Logger?.Error(e);
            return null;
        }

        // не надо делать матрешки их try/catch
        try
        {
            ListResult lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListResult>(resp.Content);
            return lists.List;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger?.Error(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Критических ошибок я вижу две.

Первая - обработка ошибок. Никогда нельзя просто так брать и проглатывать исключение - это затрудняет диагностику и приводит к ситуации, когда программа просто не работает и ничего не понятно. У вас же по коду просто раскиданы пустые catch-блоки! Так делать нельзя. Добавьте хотя бы вывод в лог или какой-нибудь MessageBox. Можно использовать `Trace.TraceError(...)` если настройка логов не входит в задачу.

Вторая - вы зачем-то многократно парсите json. Парсите, потом преобразуете в строку и снова парсите... Нахрена?! Потратьте немного времени чтобы изучить что пакет newtonsoft.json умеет. К примеру, у всех токенов есть метод [`ToObject<...>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm). И забудьте про dynamic и ToString()! Это не те возможности которые следует использовать регулярно.

Исправление этих двух проблем переведет ваш код из категории "говнокод" в категорию "код новичка".

Answer (score 1):

Мне не нравится, что вы возвращаете `null` вместо пустой коллекции, когда ловите ошибку.

Обычно, принято возвращать пустую коллекцию, что избавляет от того, что перед итерированием ее нужно проверять.

Comment: это был до меня и я сохранил стиль

Answer (score -1):

Упростил десериализацию:

```
 public class Quest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 var json2 = @"[{
                            'obj':{ 'order':['q957','q479','q214'],
                                    'quests':{
                                             'q214':{'width':10,'name':'Телефон','id':'q214','type':'free'},
                                             'q479':{'width':15,'name':'Имя','type':'free','id':'q479'},
                                             'q957':{'width':100,'name':'Город','id':'q957','type':'free'}
                                            },
                                    'id':'a525',
                                    'param':{'system':0,'name':'Данные пользователя', 'multi':0}},
                            'request.id':'fake -EC06814E-E35B-11E8-B22D-F854389B935E',
                            'duration':0.042354,
                            '_ehid':'212432.23074209719.1541684457'
                        }]";

dynamic root = JArray.Parse(json2);

IEnumerable<Quest> quests2 = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)root[0].obj.quests).Select(x => (Quest)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quest>(x.Value.ToString()));
```

Как ещё можно упростить? Нужно как-то избавиться от dynamic

Comment: динамик не нужен, так как `JArray.Parse`, как ни странно, возвращает объект типа `JArray`

Comment: Используйте кнопку "править" для дополнений вопроса. Ответы для этих целей не предназначены.